# Saving images in the res/drawable directory

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use the Tab layout in android and I am having a real problem when trying to save pictures I want to use as the tab icons in the res/drawable directory! :( Can somebody help me with this please???? Any help would much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "real problem"?

Answer (score 0):

Try make sure all the pictures are .png format and maybe of a certain scale.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a bit more information.  Are other images in the `res\drawable` directory working correctly?  Are you aiming at 160 dpi for your images?  You should probably add some code snippets.

Find an example using the tabs.  Edit one of the resource files, not changing anything else, and verify it does what you expect.

Also, items in the `res\drawable` directory will occasionally have the format switched if there is a more efficient loseless conversion.

Start with the example code in `ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Tabs2.java`; you need to create a "factory", but it is all boilerplate.